# How to choose a 3A power supply for a project involving a micro controller?

Tags: power-supply, power

I am designing a project where a ATMega 328p chip triggers a 3V step up transformer to produce a 7kV spark gap.

I have found some 3A transistors which I can use as obviously the 238p cannot supply a high current to the boost module.

However I want the project to have one wall socket so it directly plugs into the wall.

What is the best way to power this. I know one can buy 5V 3A wall warts. However my concern is that they will not be sufficiently regulated to provide a stable 5V to the 328P chip.

Would it be better to get a higher voltage wall wart and then use a L7805 before the 328p and then a higher current regulator before the 3A device?

Or is there a better option all together?

Comment: Technically speaking the ATMega doesn't use 5V either, it only uses 5V for driving the IO pins and they don't really care *too much* about less than stellar regulation whereas the sensitive core logic actually has it's own internal linear regulator anyway. I forget the ATMega's core voltage, but it's probably in the ball park of 1.2-1.8V. TLDR: Pretty much all micros have their own internal regulators for the sensitive core logic and the IO isn't usually too bothered by a little noise (with the exception of the ADC). You can get any power supply at any voltage with any quality, it's just $$$.

Comment: Assume that the quality of power supply 5 V,3+ amps is okay. Use 5 V as is. Use a simple relay or a very low on resistance FET to turn on the 3A Device. ATMega only drives the gate of the FET, hence a current of about nothing(nA) is sufficient. You can search for MOSFET as a switch. later look for MOSFETs with drain current more than 3A at Gate voltage less than ~4V. By the way, you haven't defined how frequently the load has to be switched, what the load is. Hence, no answer will be accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Good to know that I can use any power supply.

Would you suggest a MOSFET rather than a bipolar transistor for this task?

The high current load is a step-up boost module to create 7KV to be used to generate a small spark gap. I have struggled to find a specific data sheet to find the actual peak current, but I am assuming around 3A. The load will only be run for a very short amount of time, in the 10s of milli seconds.

Can I step down the 5V to a lower voltage, say 3V for the spark gap? I guess I would need more than a simple linear regulator chip.

Comment: MOSFETs are generally a better idea. However I'd suggest having two separate power supplies with a common (star) ground, otherwise you may find the atmega resets when you fire the spark gap.

Comment: Thanks, is that possible while maintaining 1 wire to the mains power?